# AWS : register-container-instance - examples needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am in process of registering EC2 instance to my ECS cluster. I am bot surprised that I can not add EC2 instance using graphical UI ( That is What my experience suggests, I could be wrong.) 
Command line interface is very hard as there are no good examples. I tried to Google it. I think thi
s very complex that it needs to be..

I am running command,

aws ecs register-container-instance  --cluster default 
it needs --instance-identity-document and --instance-indentity-document-signature and few other arguments..I am able get document but some good example would help me further. Does anybody has same frustration ? Any advice

Comment: Having the same issue right now

Comment: me too, same error

Answer (score 1):

> I am afraid that you cannot use the “register-container-instance”
>   command (RegisterContainerInstance API). As shown in [1, 2], this
>   action is only used by the Amazon EC2 Container Service agent, and it
>   is not intended for use outside of the agent.

Answer (score -2):

Following blogpost by Jeff Barr explains how to add EC2 instances to ECS cluster.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-container-service-in-action/.

I hope this can be simplified in future release